# Using Castle NHibernate Integration Facility with Castle Core 1.2

Tags: nhibernate, dependencies, castle-windsor, windsor-nhfacility

I'm working on a personal learning project to help me understand how to use Castle Windsor and Fluent NHibernate. So far written an ASP.NET MVC project which does some basic dependency injection of services into controllers.

My project contains the following references:

```
Castle.Core 1.2.0.0
Castle.DynamicProxy 2.2.0.0
Castle Windsor 2.1.0.0
NHibernate.Core 2.1.2.4000
FluentNHibernate 1.1.0.694
```

I managed to get these playing nicely together by taking the NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.dll from the Active Record project as I found suggested elsewhere on StackOverflow.

Id like to use the NHibernate Integration Facility but I'm having a bit of a dependency nightmare trying to find a compatible version. All of this is still very new to me and I think Ive done well to get as far as I have!

What am I going to have to do in order to add the NHibernate Integration Facility to my project? Does a compatible version exist and if so where can I find it? Alternatively is it possible to compile a version that works with the dependencies Im using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a compatible version, but you must build it yourself as there have been no releases of the library.

Open a command prompt, and given you have [installed git](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list-):

- git clone https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration.git
- cd Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration
- git reset --hard aef2d2ef324071d961474b41fcb312dd48d0e946.
  (Resetting to commit aef2d2e gives you the version of the libs you use.)

Now run ClickToBuild.cmd and you'll find the facility assembly in the build folder.

If you don't want to install git you can also download the source from Github for this commit by clicking on the download button at this link:
https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Facilities.NHibernateIntegration/commit/aef2d2ef324071d961474b41fcb312dd48d0e946

Comment: Thank you! I do have git installed but Ive been struggling to get it working through the company proxy. The link to github you provided worked perfectly, many thanks again!